# Video Feed - correct design pattern

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm pretty new to Flutter and StatefulWidgets etc. still aren't fully internalised yet, so I'm wondering what the correct design pattern will be for the following situation:

- I have a feed of `VideoWidgets` (using `video_player`) in a `listView`
- Tapping a `listViewItem` should play the video in the `VideoWidget` statefulWidget (Already I'm not sure how to propagate the tap through to the widget)
- Pressing 'play all' should go through the `videoWidgets` chronologically and play each video.

So far I've tried saving a reference to each `VideoWidget` in a map with the `videoID` even then I'm not entirely sure how to take it from there.

VideoWidgets are displayed like this:

```
Container(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              // play
              playQueue.clear();
              currentQueueIndex = 0;
              _addToQueue(message);
              _playQueue();
            },
            child: Center(
              child: LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                  VideoWidget widget = VideoWidget(
                      play: false, url: message.resourceURL, key: _key);
                  videoWidgets[message.messageId] = _key;
                  return widget;
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

And the `VideoWidget` itself was built from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62749081/1570908

What would be the correct way to approach this problem in Flutter/Dart?

Thanks.
Mike

**EDIT:** I managed to get it working using the map and `bool` to determine if it should play and then `setState` when a tap was clicked, however, this reloads the whole `listView` (which I expected) but as the videos are remote all the video players show the loading indicator and beginning pulling from remote again, so not a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out a nice way of doing this using state and I've come to the conclusion that I probably didn't need to as the video_player was already created and ready to be played. Instead, I saved a reference to the `VideoPlayerController` for each `listViewItem` and just called `controller.play()` on the correct one.